# Ransomware hack usb controller

Tags: windows-7, usb, ransomware

Apology to poor english , i am 56 year old , from macedonia , maybe the superuser isnt a best place to ask , but google lied to me some times so i dont trust it ,

My boss in work is dumb as a bike and doesnt spend money to update computer and softwares so he pays some "it" guy to install a cracked windows 7 and office 2010 for 10$ ,

Also he dont pay for back ups or even external off line hard disk to back up the document's or a cloud storaging

Our work pc's were hacked by some ransomware , Also plugged in was my usb as i was transfering a work document to another work pc because network share file its disabled in my work network

In the usb was some work documents , very important , boss says he will raise all our pay's to 600 euro when the decryption its found ,

I want to check no more ransom web-site and use a crypto sherif to see if there is a decryption or wait some time and hope it to be released , but i am scared if it will hack my personal laptop pc , i watched some thing in youtube it says that a ransomware hacks your usb to destroy computer , but i dont think is other way to check no more ransom web-site as it needs 2 file's encripted file's

Pleas tell me if usb can hack my laptop , i also have a 4gb blank usb to use for dual boot maybe if it is windows only ransomware ,i think it is

Thank's you for all answer,

Have good day

Comment: You need to recover from backups and if no backups, your data is lost.

Comment: @John i want to check nomoreransom web site and also backup the data from usb in case some time decryption is found

Comment: You would need to pay for decryption and that is not considered to be a good idea. You might lose your money and not get the key.

Comment: work + ransomware - backups = no work. Maybe he'll reconsider the economy of that 'wisdom' in future. In the meantime, why risk your own computer? If he wants you to try cracking it so badly, he can buy a new machine himself.

Comment: @Tetsujin He is dumb as a bike, thats why

Comment: You know what happens to a bike if you let go of it?  It falls over. He's going to either have to learn to stand alone, or pay for support. I'd start job-hunting. It's not your problem. BTW, if network file sharing is off, then USB is probably how the ransomware was distributed in the first place. He also needs to pay for some decent corporate endpoint antivirus solution/

Comment: @Tetsujin The usb was fine until the pc's were hacked by the ransomware , we use unpatched windows  7  last updated from 2013

Comment: **All** versions of Windows 7 are 'unpatched' It went completely out of support 18 months ago. Of course the USB was fine before. The computers were fine before too… if there's no file sharing, then the ransomware was passed by USB or shared links - possibly by someone looking for other "free" software. Half of that stuff is just put out to catch the unwary, & your company's IT policy, if I can even call it that, seems the very epitome of "unwary".

Comment: @karel it is , thanks